# Exit cron job after launching program

Tags: bash, cron

I have this .sh script that I want to execute once a day as a cron job. It checks if a specific process is still running (qbittools) and if not launches it again. This works, however the cron job never exits unless the qbittools process dies. This creates a queue of cron jobs as days pass.

Is there a way to execute the else statement and a few second later exit the cron job regardless of its execution?

qbittools should never end. This is purely to restart it if it dies.

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -x "qbittools" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Running"
else
    qbittools reannounce -s 192.168.1.77:10095 -U xxxx -P xxxx &
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Start once with a start script (without cron): `while true; do qbittools reannounce -s 192.168.1.77:10095 -U xxxx -P xxxx; done`

Comment: or let systemd run your script, monitor it and restart it if it died (option: `Restart=on-failure`).

Answer (score 0):

I think it works now, I was just missing a disown, see below:

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -x "qbittools" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Running"
else
    qbittools reannounce -s 192.168.1.77:10095 -U xxxx -P xxxx &>/dev/null & disown 
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: I think you'll want to redirect stdin as well ( `</dev/null` ) to fully disassociate the program from the shell.